# Use views with the Homebox module

Tags: views, 7

Is it possible to use views inside the [Homebox module](http://drupal.org/project/homebox)? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is!

You embed blocks into Homebox regions, so just create a block display of your view, and include it into your Homebox on the layout page.

Any disabled blocks will be listed at the bottom, just pick a region for them!